# Django 'migration is applied before its dependency' when running any migration commands

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-migrations

I am using Django 3.0.2 that is connected to a local MySQL database.My project current has 2 apps, '*accounts*' and '*home*'.

I dropped all the tables in my database after updating some of my model fields and I removed all the files in the migrations folder except `__init__.py`. Trying to start the dev server shows an error: `Dependency on app with no migrations: accounts`, so I ran `python manage.py makemigrations` which returned this

```
Migrations for 'accounts':
  accounts\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model User
Migrations for 'home':
  home\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model Idea
    - Create model Reply
```

After this, running the server gives a warning saying

> You have 1 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): accounts.
>   Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

Doing so gives me an `InconsistentMigrationHistory` exception:
`Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency accounts.0001_initial on database 'default'`

---

Running `python manage.py showmigrations` returns this:

```
accounts
 [ ] 0001_initial
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
 [X] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length
 [X] 0011_update_proxy_permissions
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
home
 [X] 0001_initial
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
```

---

I've tried runing the commands in different orders but it eventually comes to the same result. I can provide more details about the app if needed.

Comment: run migrations for specific apps `manage.py migrate accounts` then run the other migration

Comment: It still gives me the `InconsistentMigrationHistory` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you haven't cleared your model class. You can delete all files under migrations directory of your app directory excluding **init**.py file. 
You have to Drop table django_migrations. 
After you delete then run

```
python manage.py makemigrations account
python manage.py makemigrations home
python manage.py migrate
```